# Resizing list items in a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, textview, height

Is there an elegant way to ask a ListView how many list items currently fit on the screen?

Or the other way around: Is is possible to tell a ListView to make its list items that big (by increasing their height) that exactly n items fit on the screen? In my case the list items are simple TextViews.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to do this is probably get your `ListView` height and create your own View that measures itself to be `listView.getHeight()/N` (where n is the number of views you want on screen at once).

Comment: Oh, you're right. That's really easy. I tried `textView.setHeight(parent.getHeight() / n);` in the overriden  `getView` method. But this doesn't work properly. Maybe I have to consider the delimiters? The TextViews a slightly to high.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain you need to wait until the ListView has been measured properly or you need to first measure it yourself.  You can accomplish the former with a GlobalLayoutListener and the later by creating a MeasureSpec and calling measure yourself followed by a `getHeight()`.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain I also realize I may be misunderstanding your issue, are you saying getHeight() is returning a value that's bigger than you expect (such that getHeight()/n is also bigger than desired)?  If so why not try setting a max height or something on the textView or you may need to use your own view that you can force to be exactly the size you want it.

Comment: There is a straight line between the items of a ListView separating those items from each other. I think this line doesn't belong to the item itself. So the total height of the ListView is calculated as heights of the items plus the heights of the separating lines. `textView.setHeight((parent.getHeight() / numberOfItems) - 2);` worked quite well for me but maybe there is a way to access the height of those lines directly.

Answer (score 2):

YOU can use `list.getLastVisiblePosition()` and subtract `list.getFirstVisiblePosition()`

```
int count = list.getLastVisiblePosition() - list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

Hope this helps